# Syntax of let with and without =

Tags: macros, syntax

While reading the documentation of `endnotes` I have found the following line:

```
\let\footnote=\endnote
```

Until now I always wrote `\let` without a `=`, so I would have written

```
\let\footnote\endnote
```

And both methods seem to achieve the same. So is there any difference in using the `=` and if yes, what is it?

Comment: The `=` is optional; but in some cases it is not.

Comment: @egreg Would you mind giving an example of when it is not optional?

Comment: @TeXnician note that the optional = is common to all tex assignments `\textwidth=6cm` is the same as `\textwidth 6cm`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax for `\let` is

```
\let<control sequence><equals><one optional space><token>
```

so an = and a space are consumed while parsing. This only makes a difference if you want to let something equal to `=` or a space when you have to use

```
\let\foo==
```

as the first `=` is discarded

`<equals>` here is texbook syntax for any number of optional spaces, optionally followed by one `=`.

The latex format has the following line to define `\let` a command name to be a space token

```
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \:  % this makes \@sptoken a space token
```

note that `\:␣` expands to `\let\@sptoken=␣␣` and the = and one optional `␣` are discarded so `\@sptoken` is let to `␣` .

If you just went

```
\let\@sptoken=  %
```

then the two `␣` would be tokenised as a single space as usual and so `\let` would discard them both as an optional space.

(Using `␣` to represent a space in a visible manner in this discussion)

Comment: Spaces are such interesting things in TeX.

Answer (score 10):

The `=` is optional, but there are places where it needs to be explicitly used.

Suppose you want to implement a syntax such as `\bold{text in bold}`. If you look in this [witty article by Arsenau, Chen and Eijkhout on TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb15-1/tb42arseneau.pdf) you'll find

[image]

Let's look at the wizard and guru solutions. Both want to remove a brace, but the first one fails in case the user says `\bold x`.  With the guru solution this doesn't happen, because the `{` is required by the syntax.

More generally, when one wants to remove a token with the `\let\next` trick, the equal and the space are *mandatory*. Consider

```
\def\removeA{\let\next}
\def\removeB{\let\next=}
\def\removeC{\let\next= }
```

and try them:

```
\removeA =xyz \show\next
\removeB =xyz \show\next
\removeC =xyz \show\next
```

In the first case `\next` will be `the character x`, not the token immediately following the macro. What about the difference between `\removeB` and `\removeC`? Try

```
\expandafter\removeA\space xyz \show\next
\expandafter\removeB\space xyz \show\next
\expandafter\removeC\space xyz \show\next
```

Now only the latter makes `\next` into `blank space`.

Note that most likely `\removeC` will appear as the trailing token in the definition of another command, that maybe absorbs an argument, so a space token can be found even without resorting to the trick above for forcing one.